# EJS getting specific data from MySQL

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ejs

[Github project link](https://github.com/AEkman/Quiz)

So, I am making a Quiz creation application using EJS as templating engine with jQuery, Bootstrap and MySql.

I'm trying to loop out the corresponding answers to to the questions based on the quiz.

So let's say I'm starting the quiz with quizd2 via route call.
I'm gettings the quiz 2 with 2 questions. I'm looping through with forEach() in ejs code but i can't figure out how to loop the correct answers to the correct question?

```
<div class="content col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <h1>
        <% loadQuizes.forEach(function (quizes) { %>
            <h2><%= quizes.quizName %></h2> <!-- Load the name of quiz-->
        <% }) %>
    </h1>
    <form action="/takequiz" method="POST">
        <% quizQuestions.forEach(function (questions) { %> <!-- Load question by question WHERE questionQuizId = ? -->
            <div class="well well-sm">
                <h3><%= questions.question %></h3> <!-- Print question -->
                    <% answers.forEach(function (ans) { %><!-- Load answers by answers WHERE answerQuestionid = ? -->
                    <%= ans.answer %><br> <!-- Print answers followed by checkbox -->
                    <% }) %> <!-- End loading answers -->
            </div> <!-- well -->
        <% }) %> <!-- End loading question -->
    </form> <!-- form --> </div> <!-- content -->
```

I do have a table that looks like this:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM quiz;
+--------+------------------------+---------------------+--------------+-------+-------+
| quizId | quizName               | dateCreated         | dateFinished | times | score |
+--------+------------------------+---------------------+--------------+-------+-------+
|      1 | Solution to everything | 2017-03-03 16:14:02 | 2017-03-03   |     2 |    20 |
|      2 | Bergskedjor            | 2017-03-03 16:14:02 | 2017-03-03   |     2 |    20 |
+--------+------------------------+---------------------+--------------+-------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM question;
+------------+-------------------------------------------+----------------+
| questionId | question                                  | questionQuizid |
+------------+-------------------------------------------+----------------+
|          1 | What color is the Sky?                    |              1 |
|          2 | Vilket ├ñr v├ñrldens h├Âgsta berg?        |              2 |
|          3 | Vilket ├ñr v├ñrldens tredje h├Âgsta berg? |              2 |
+------------+-------------------------------------------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM answers;
+----------+---------------------+---------+------------------+
| answerId | answer              | correct | answerQuestionid |
+----------+---------------------+---------+------------------+
|        1 | Red                 |       0 |                1 |
|        2 | Green               |       0 |                1 |
|        3 | Blue                |       1 |                1 |
|        4 | Pink                |       0 |                1 |
|        5 | Red                 |       0 |                1 |
|        6 | Question 1 Answer 1 |       0 |                2 |
|        7 | Question 1 Answer 2 |       1 |                2 |
|        8 | Question 1 Answer 3 |       0 |                2 |
|        9 | Question 2 Answer 1 |       0 |                3 |
|       10 | Question 2 Answer 2 |       0 |                3 |
|       11 | Question 2 Answer 3 |       1 |                3 |
+----------+---------------------+---------+------------------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And of course a callback loop from hell :)

```
    app.get('/takequiz/:id', function(req, res) {
        connection.acquire(function (err, con) {
            var quizId = req.params.id;
            con.query('SELECT * FROM quiz WHERE quizId = ?', quizId, function (err, qid) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    con.query('SELECT * FROM question WHERE questionQuizId = ?', quizId, function (err, question) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        } else {
                            con.query('SELECT * FROM answers WHERE answerQuestionid IN (SELECT questionId FROM question WHERE questionQuizid = ?)', quizId, function (err, answer) {
                                console.log(answer);
                                con.release();
                                if (err) {
                                    console.log(err);
                                } else {
                                    loadQuizes = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(qid));
                                    quizQuestions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(question));
                                    answers = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(answer));
                                    res.render('takequizbyid', {
                                        loadQuizes: loadQuizes,
                                        quizQuestions: quizQuestions,
                                        answers: answers,
                                        title: 'Take quiz',
                                        classname: 'takequizbyid'
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
);
});
```

And the result looks like this:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPudU.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution with a better asked question:[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42610097/printing-mysql-data-to-ejs-document-with-foreign-keys/42611324#42611324)

Introducing logic:

```
<% quizQuestions.forEach(function (question) { %>
  <div class="well well-sm">
    <h3><%= question.question %></h3>
    <% answers.forEach(function (ans) { %>
      <% if (ans.answerQuestionid === question.questionId) { %>
        <%= ans.answer %><br>
      <% } %>
    <% }) %>
  </div> <!-- well -->
<% }) %>
```